# How do I publish this survey created in Google Docs?

Tags: google-forms, sharing

I have a student who created a Form in Google Docs using their Google Apps for Education account.  For some reason, we are unable to send this published form so that others can take the survey.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I work in a school district where students use Google Docs using their Google Apps for Education, and teachers use a regular Google Docs account.  We have been able to share documents, spreadsheets, and presentations between the Apps for Education and regular Google accounts without any problem.

We tried going to Form > Live Form and emailing that link, and we tried Form > Send Form, and no matter what the link takes me to the page to log in to the Google Apps for Education account.

I also tried having the student share the document with me as an editor.  I can see the spreadsheet, but when I try to view the live form (even though it should be shared with me as an editor) I get a message that tells me that I do not have permission to access the spreadsheet.

So... why is this happening and how can I get a link to the published survey so that people can respond?

Comment: This may seem obvious, but are you sure the student set the permissions correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Open up your form in edit mode by opening the spreadsheet and clicking "Form" --> "Edit Form" from the menu.  Near the top there should be 3 check-boxes that set permissions for the form.  The middle check box is the one that requires a login to view your form.  If you un-check this, you should be able to embed it in a web page or email, as well as email the link around.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the form in edit mode is a tick box to request GAFE sign in. Make sure this is unchecked.